# Writing a compiler

Tags: compiler-construction, bison, yacc, flex-lexer, bibtex

I basically need to make a compiler for bibtex files, such that a given bibtex database can be queried. Now I'm familiar with certain aspects of theory, like automata, grammars, SLR,LR(1) and LALR parsing. However, I still find all of that theoretical and abstract, since I've never applied it.
It would help a lot if someone could outline the solid steps required to build a compiler. I'll be using flex and bison/yacc probably, so if you could let me know how exactly the design process goes, what files are generated at what stage, what is the output at each stage, and in general how things tie together, I can probably get a more practical view of how things are done...

Thanks!

Comment: possible duplicate of [parse bibtex with flex+bison: revisited](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15305789/parse-bibtex-with-flexbison-revisited)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you sure you want to *compile*  a bibtex database into something executable? If querying is the only thing you want, than it will make more sense to translate a bibtex database into a relational one, and query it with SQL. Of course you still have to parse bibtex first, and generate a SQL code out of it, and some will call it "compiling", but it is far less complicated than the stuff in the already mentioned Dragon Book.

Bibtex syntax is extremely trivial, so you can choose any parsing approach. I would not even bother using parser generators for such a trivial grammar, and will jot a recursive descent parser instead. Depending on the language of your choice, it can be really easy (e.g., if you're using Haskell with Parsec, or even a C#).

If your additional goal is to learn the outdated tools like bison and flex, then, of course, they'll do the job too, but it is an overkill.

**Edit**: the best practical reading on the classic lex/yacc approach is http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Unix_Programming_Environment

Comment: It's for a learning assignment, so I'll have to follow the given specifications. I'll probably use C, additionally.

Comment: @Achint, does it mean that you'll have to implement a querying language too? I'll edit my answer.

Comment: Well the specifications go like this: I have to develop a compiler that compiles any BIBTEX database file into a C/C++/Java/Python/Lisp
program which can be subsequently compiled into an executable and then run so as to answer any query about the entries in the BIBTEX database file. Also flex and bison must be used. I can compile the database into another form of a database, and have some generic C/C++/Java/Python/Lisp to query it, but I can't query the raw Bibtex database using a code. I have to submit a .l and .y file, and Makefile for running them as my output.

Comment: @Achint, then you apparently have to design and implement some sort of a query language too, embedding it into your compiled code. It is a pity you've got no C# in a list of possible targets, otherwise you'd be able to use its own LINQ. But you can simulate the same behaviour with Lisp. If your specification does not force you to use C and bison, you'd better stick with Lisp and, say, http://www.cliki.net/cl-peg

Comment: Specifications don't force C, but I think Bison is a must. :( Or maybe yacc, but I'm sure one of them. I'm a bit unclear on how the exact stages go. Where exactly do I have to embed the the code for the querying language? From what I understand right now, I'll need to write a lexical analyzer using flex/lex, which will give an output of tokens, and I'll need to make a proper grammar according to the BIBTEX syntax and write a parser using yacc/bison that will take the tokens input and tell me whether the string is accepted or not and output a syntax tree?

Comment: @Achint, right, you have to write a lexer, chain its output to a bison-generated parser, which will either construct an abstract syntax tree (not needed in such a trivial case) or immediately print the parsed data into your target language static structure initialisers. The generated code should be linked with a hand-written program which executes queries against that static structures. Any lex+yacc example layout will be sufficient, see the book I've mentioned in my answer for the simplest one.

Comment: I got the book, I'll start reading it. Thanks for the huge help, but I'm sure I'll have like a hundred questions on the way, so I'll be posting again :P

Answer (score 1):

I am not a compiler expert but I do know that this book is actually regarded as necessary reading for anyone that wants to write a compiler.  Yes the cover is antiquated but from what I have read it still has many good patterns relevant to code compilation:

[http://www.amazon.com/Compilers-Principles-Techniques-Alfred-Aho/dp/0201100886](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0201100886)

Comment: Yeah I was referring to that book, but then again, the whole concept omes across as abstract to me, probably because I haven't seen the output of any of the steps.